# How to monitor log app wise usage report RAM CPU Battery and stop RAM resident apps from starting at boot

Tags: ram, task-management, services, resource-monitoring, force-stop

How to monitor log app wise usage report RAM CPU Battery and stop RAM resident apps from starting at boot

Many time my Android 5.0 & 6.0 mobile become slow while working i checked it In process stat in developer mode that there are many of apps running and using RAM even after closing the app it means they are memory resident may be for notification and running in background.

We can force stop from app or kill process but it's for time being now my queries

1. Any App to.Record whole day log report for all apps how much total RAM CPU battery it's using while working on app and after closing the app means RAM using statistics app wise for whole day weak or.month
2. How to kill running apps proccess forcefully stop for temp running and freeing the ram urgently.
3. How to permanently stop (not uninstalling app) the apps or background services from.startup or disable from memory resident as and whenever we boot or start those apps run in background. Is there any way in Android to stop from.running in startup or resident memory RAM after closing app.

Comment: If your old Android phone is getting slow and slower is because the apps grow larger and larger as they are designed for recent Android phones that have 4 to 10 times more RAM of old devices. On newer Android devices you can restrict background activities of apps a bit but on Android 5/6 as far as I remember only some custom ROMs had this feature.

Comment: @Robert is there any 3rd party apps which can do it .. ifor monitoring battery I seen Greenwich or accurate battery and for ram  I am.using ram monitor or resource monitor.... I had downloaded a task manager which can kill process buts it's  not working much fine